# ISCHANGED always return TRUE on RichTextArea

Tags: validation-rule, richtextarea

I have a validation rule that should prevent changing of Rich Text Area field after creation. In order achieve this I created a validation rule that use `ISCHANGED(RickTextArea__c)` formula, but it fires always no matter field was or was not chagned.

Is this a known limitation of salesforce?
Is there any workaround apart from coding?